# Perl error message perhaps you forgot to load

Tags: perl

I have a first Perl program that uses [`Mail::Sender`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Sender):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

use autodie;    # die if problem reading or writing a file

use Mail::Sender;

my $av_tmp_SENDER = Mail::Sender->new( {
    from    => 'absender@absender.de',
    to      => 'empf@empf.de',
    subject => 'Funktionstest',
} );

$av_tmp_SENDER->MailMsg( {
    to      => 'empf@empf.de',
    subject => 'Funktionstest',
    msg     => "noch ein bisschen text"
} );

print "Die e-Mail wurde verschickt";  # The email was sent
```

Then I get this error message:

```
Can't locate object method "MailMsg" via package "-1" (perhaps you forgot to load "-1"?) at ./av_perl_02.pl line
```

Can someone please give a beginner a hint?!

Comment: **1** Please use English. **2** *Always* `use strict`!

Comment: @Biffen `s/Please/Always/`

Comment: @andlrc: I don't think any harm comes from a little politeness, especially when "please" is used as Biffen did, without any sense of propriety at all. It's also important with a Perl question to distinguish *please write your posts in the English language* from *please `use English`* that IMO is a horrible thing, second only to `use diagnostics`

Comment: I will for next posts - thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that what `Mail::Sender->new` returned is valid.  In this case, it is returning `-1`.  Then when you try to call `MailMsg` on the variable that has the value `-1`, Perl interprets the value as a class (package) name and assumes you mean to call the method on that class.

A good way to test the return value of a constructor is with the `ref` function:

```
my $av_tmp_SENDER = Mail::Sender->new(...)
if ( ref( $av_tmp_SENDER ) eq 'Mail::Sender' ) {
    # Use the new object
}
else {
    # Print a message
}
```

Of course, the docs for that module may indicate other checks.  For instance, what does it mean that it returned `-1` rather than `undef` or `0`?

Answer (score 1):

...and welcome to Stack Overflow and to Perl

I'm sorry if the dissenters put you off, but in the end they are right—Stack Overflow is an English language site

The problem is that you didn't specify an SMTP server when you created the `Mail::Server` object. Most internet service providers give you access to their SMTP server as part of the deal

If you don't know the URL for your SMTP server then you should check on line or call support to find out what it is. You will probably also need to provide your username and password

You need to check with them and provide the  URL for the server to the `new` call. The code below assumes that you have a gmail account, and Google's SMTP server is at `smtp.gmail.com`

This code will report any errors, in either the call to `new` or to `MailMsg`. Error code are negative numbers, and you can read their meaning in the [*Return codes* section of the `Mail::Sender` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Sender#Return-codes)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Mail::Sender;

my $sender = Mail::Sender->new( {
    smtp    => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    authid  => 'my.email@gmail.com',
    authpwd => 'Herringbone-pattern-1989',
} );

die "Return code $sender" unless ref $sender;

my $status = $sender->MailMsg( {
    to      => 'my.friend@gmail.com',
    from    => 'my.email@gmail.com',
    subject => 'Funktionstest',
    msg     => 'noch ein bisschen text',
} );

die "Return code $status" unless ref $status;

print "Die e-Mail wurde verschickt";
```

Comment: O.K. - thanks for hint - as I said, I am a total newbie.

In this example I simply want to send an e-Mail as I normally do with shell command mailx, since my ubuntu mashine has a postfix installation running.

I was looking for examples in the net and came across this one. But there must be a way just to send away the mail and let the existing postfix handle it.
By the way: postfix is configured only to accept mails from local network.

Thanks
Karl-Heinz